# How to record usb audio and monitor at the same time

Tags: pi-3, usb, audio, raspbian-stretch, alsa

I have a usb audio device plugged into my Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian Stretch. Recording to an mp3 with sox works fine with this line:

```
AUDIODEV=dsnooped rec -c 1 -q /media/usbstick/recording/soxrecording.mp3
```

Now I would like to monitor while I am recording. But when I do:

```
arecord -D dsnooped -f S16_LE -c 1 -r 192000 -d 2000000 | aplay -D dsnooped
```

I get an Error:

```
arecord: main:788: audio open error: Device or resource busy
```

`/etc/asound.conf` looks like this:

```
pcm.dsnooped {

type dsnoop
ipc_key 234884

slave {
    pcm "hw:1"
    channels 2
}
```

What can I do to record to file and listen at the same time ?

Maybe I need to create 2 virtual channels out of one audio input, but how?